# Creating a button with php that calls a JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript, button

**PHP**

```
$output_string .= '<td><button id="changeButton" type="button" onclick="deleteAdress('. $row['adresses_id'] .', "'. $row['adresses_street'] .'");">Ta bort</button></td>';
```

**Javascript**

```
function deleteAdress(adressID, adressStreetName) {   

    alert(adressID);

}
```

I'm trying to create a button in php with onclick should make an alert box (for now). When i send numbers it works. But when one string contains text i stops working. Nothing. No alert box at all. I have also tried without the double quotes.

If you can see any problem please tell me. :)

Comment: Does the string have apostrophes in it? You need to escape values before outputting them, especially into HTML attributes.

Comment: try $output_string .= '<td><button id="changeButton" type="button" onclick="deleteAdress('. json_encode($row['adresses_id']) .', "'. json_encode($row['adresses_street']) .'");">Ta bort</button></td>';

Comment: Nothing. - you should learn how to use developer tools. Any browser has it. Usually could be called with F12 (you may need to install firebug in FF). With this problem you could check resulting output and errors in console. They are really helpful.

Comment: Please don't ever use a "button that calls JS". Inline event handler will always complicate things when developing extensive JS scripts. Just set up the event handler from a separate JS code block or file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to add escaped quotes

```
$output_string .= '<td><button id="changeButton" type="button" onclick="deleteAdress(\''. htmlspecialchars($row['adresses_id'], ENT_QUOTES) .'\', \''. htmlspecialchars($row['adresses_street'], ENT_QUOTES) .'\');">Ta bort</button></td>';
```

Comment: what happens if `$row['adresses_street']` contains `'`

Comment: It'll break of course. The value you're posting should be sanitized first. You should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php this function to do so.

Comment: Edited to add the special char escape.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
 $output_string .= '<td><button id="changeButton" type="button" onclick="deleteAdress("'. $row['adresses_id'] .'", "'. $row['adresses_street'] .'");">Ta bort</button></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just add quotes when calling the function:

```
onclick="deleteAdress(\''. $row['adresses_id'] .'\', "'. $row['adresses_street'] .'");
```